# Looping images in bootstrap carousal rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I'm having some trouble trying to display multiple images attached to a job post using bootstrap carousal. Here's the original code without the caraousal template:

```
<% if @job.images.attached? %>
<% (0...@job.images.count).each do |image| %>

<%= image_tag(@job.images[image]) %>

<% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= image_tag "missing.jpg" %>

                <% end %>
```

Below is a bootstrap carousal example i used from w3 schools and it works fine when i tested it on my app.

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

So far i've tried :

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <% (0...@job.images.count).each do |image| %>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to=#{image} class="active"></li>
    <% end %>

  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% (0...@job.images.count).each do |image| %>
    <div class="item active">
    <%= image_tag(@job.images[image]) %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

The images are stacking up against each other, and when i click on the next slide, all the images disappear.I'm not sure exactly what to put in the data-slide classes, i'm suspecting that's the cause of the problem.

***UPDATE***

This code is working when the image slider automatically plays, but manually clicking on an image slider causes the entire carousal to disappear:

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to=#{index} <%= index == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '' %>></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <div class="item <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
    <%= image_tag image %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks like you're giving the `active` class to every image in the slideshow. Secondly, there are easier methods of iterating through your images.

Something like this should work:

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to=#{index} <%= index == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '' %>></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @job.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <div class="item <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
    <%= image_tag image %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks this works when i let the slide automatically play, but if i manually click on an image everything disappears

Comment: Well, I'm guessing some of your bootstrap code isn't quite right then. You'd be better off taking your examples from https://getbootstrap.com than from W3 Schools